Is there a way to use Ehcache 3 with JCache in reactive Spring 6
After migration to Spring 6, i found out that Ehcache 3 must be configured through using JCache:
@Bean
override fun cacheManager(): org.springframework.cache.CacheManager {
    return JCacheCacheManager(createInMemoryCacheManager())
}

private fun createInMemoryCacheManager(): CacheManager {
    val caches: Map<String, CacheConfiguration<*, *>> = createCaches()
    val cachingProvider = getCachingProvider();
    val configuration = DefaultConfiguration(
        caches,
        cachingProvider.defaultClassLoader,
        DefaultPersistenceConfiguration(File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")))
    )
    return getCacheManager(cachingProvider, configuration)
}

private fun getCachingProvider(): EhcacheCachingProvider {
    return Caching.getCachingProvider() as EhcacheCachingProvider
}

private fun getCacheManager(provider: EhcacheCachingProvider, configuration: DefaultConfiguration): CacheManager {
    return provider.getCacheManager(provider.defaultURI, configuration)
}

However, it seems that JCache has no support for reactive Spring. From the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/cache/annotations.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-reactive it looks like CaffeineCacheManager is indeed able to process Flux, but there is nothing about how to make the same for JCacheCacheManager. So currently the following method
@Cacheable("searchCache")
    override fun searchIssues(jql: String, includedFields: List<String>, maxResults: Int): Mono<SearchResult>

throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCache does not support CompletableFuture-based retrieval.
So is there a way to configure Ehcache 3 with reactive Spring 6.1+ version to work together? What CacheManager should I use to wrap Ehcache configuration?
